# simple faq module on joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

Somebody knows a simple faq module? Or how to make the facts as in the picture on the link so that you can take anywhere in the template?

http://extensions.joomla.org//components/com_mtree/img/listings/m/17933.png

I use joomla 1.7

Comment: Do you need to do anything 'fancy' with those FAQs? Because it looks like just regular HTML will do fine - no need to bloat your installation with unnecessary extensions if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, but there are tons of FAQ extensions.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/faq

Comment: I searched but I could not found the right, and decided to ask here. Thanks for reply.